# JS/Vue: How to make a select dropdown for US States autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have an array of state objects:

```
options = [
    {text: "California", value:"CA"},
    {text: "New York", value: "NY"},
]
```

Browser autocomplete works when I set the v-model to only `value` field:

```
<select>
    <option v-model="selectedState" v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
       {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**///  selectedState = "NY"**

But I need the selectedState v-model to be the object and that is what is stopping autocomplete from filling in the state:

```
<select>
    <option v-model="selectedState" v-for="option in options" :value="option.value">
       {{ option.text }}
    </option>
</select>
```

**///  selectedState = {"text": "New York", "value": "NY"}**

Do I have any options to accomplish this?

Comment: You can try this one https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/autocompletes/

Comment: I'd rather not bring in Vuetify

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use computed property to return desire object from selected value

```
    computed: {
        selectedState() {
            return this.states.find( i => i.value == this.selected );
        }
    }
```

Here is [Codepen sample](https://codepen.io/MNSY22/pen/pojLYPB)

Comment: thanks! looked promising but it looks like `datalist` element isn't supported in IE11 according to caniuse.com

Comment: It was simple sample to show how implement your code

Comment: Thank you Mohsen...sorry, I thought it was reliant on datalist being used

Comment: Do not use IE11 anymore!